# Style and center stripe button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stripe-payments

I am trying to center and style the Stripe checkout button that says update card on it. I also would like to make the card number input look normal but readonly I know the disabled look is bootstrap but how can I fix that using just classes?

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <h3>Payment Details</h3>
</div>
<form role="form" id="cardForm" action="/user/billing" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Card Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input id="card-num" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX {{user.stripe.last4}}" name="card" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id="cardFormError" class="alert alert-danger hidden" role="alert">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</form>

<form action="/user/billing" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_HwlcQ0e8VwlFkQJu46vynuPT"
    data-amount=""
    data-name="Asset Management"
    data-description="Update your card details"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-currency="usd"
    data-label="Update Card"
    data-zip-code="true"
    data-allow-remember-me="false"
    data-email="{{user.email}}">
  </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
To achive the above effect, apply `text-align: center;` to the `body`,

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Apply `background-color: white !important;` to `.form-control`,

```
.form-control {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

And apply `margin: 0 auto;` to the `divs`.

```
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You should probably also remove the extra close div tag at the end of the first form.

```css
.form-control {
  background-color: white !important;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="page-header">
  <h3>Payment Details</h3>
</div>
<form role="form" id="cardForm" action="/user/billing" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Card Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input id="card-num" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX {{user.stripe.last4}}" name="card" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id="cardFormError" class="alert alert-danger hidden" role="alert">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form action="/user/billing" method="POST">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-key="pk_test_HwlcQ0e8VwlFkQJu46vynuPT" data-amount="" data-name="Asset Management" data-description="Update your card details" data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto" data-currency="usd" data-label="Update Card" data-zip-code="true" data-allow-remember-me="false" data-email="{{user.email}}">

  </script>
</form>
```

(The stripe doesn't pop up in the snippet, but the exact same code works fine in JSFiddle)

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/sLueh77q/

Comment: Thanks this got me almost what I wanted changed 1 thing and its perfect.

Comment: @JoshKirby I'm glad to have helped. Out of interest, what did you need to change?

Comment: The body align had to create a class to center it al the rest of the stuff moved too and that caused issues

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Add this lines:

```
<style>
  .form-control[readonly] {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .text-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

And at `<form action="/user/billing" method="POST">` add `class="text-center"`. Like this: `<form action="/user/billing" class="text-center" method="POST">`.